# PHP and mysql not INSERTing

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Register </title>
</head>
<body>

Thanks for showing interest, please register below.
<br>


<br/>
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
<br>

</br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<br>

</br>
Age:      <input type="text" name="age">
<br>

</br>
Car:      <input type="text" name="car">
<br>


<input type="submit" value="register"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset fields"/>
</form>

<?php

    //db connect
    $host="localhost"; 
    $dbuser="site1login";
    $dbpass="site1login";
    $dbname="login";
    $tblname="userdata";

    //form post
    $Username=$_POST['username'];
    $Password=$_POST['password'];
    $Age=$_POST['age'];
    $Car=$_POST['car'];
    $con = mysql_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass") or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdata` (Username,Password,Age,Car) VALUES ($Username, $Password, $Age, $Car)" or die(mysql_error()));
    echo "Success!";

?>

</body>

</html>
```

So, that's my code - I'm confused - it doesn't work - it says "success", but not inserted e anything

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: While singles' answer is the correct one, I suggest you echo out the insert statement in the future.  It would be pretty obvious right away that the statement was incorrectly formatted.

Comment: You also need to check for a submittion, it tries to submit when you first go to the form.

Comment: Why was this voted down? If I have an error - tell me, it's my question - don't just vote down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following portion -

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdata` (Username,Password,Age,Car) VALUES 
             ($Username, $Password, $Age, $Car)" or die(mysql_error()));
echo "Success!";
```

into this -

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO userdata (Username,Password,Age,Car) VALUES 
          ('$Username', '$Password', '$Age', '$Car')");

if($result)
{
    echo "Success!";
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());    // Thanks to Pekka for pointing this out.
}
```

If the above doesn't work, try checking if your connection parameters are ok and if MySQL is running.

Also you should test the `$resut` value to check whether any successful query execution has occured -

```
if($result)
{
    // Successful query execution
}
else
{
    // Some error occured while executing query.
    // Show some useful information using echo/print.
    // Then stop execution after taking other necessary steps
}
```

**Edit**

As Pekka has mentioned, your database is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) attack since you are not sanitizing your input. You should use at least [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) method to ensure that this doesn't occur.

Comment: Hey there, thanks very much! that works but I `$result` doesn't exist after the query

Comment: @Pekka: It's fixed ( at least, I think :-s )

Comment: @Neurofluxation: See the edited version and try it. I think it should work now.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted before me, you are missing quotes around the field values. Also, this construction is severely flawed:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdata` (Username,Password,Age,Car) 
          VALUES ($Username, $Password, $Age, $Car)" or die(mysql_error()));
```

the `or die` is inside the query parameter. Not sure how that can work at all.

Remove the `or die` part and do error handling like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdata` (Username,Password,Age,Car) 
          VALUES ('$Username', '$Password', '$Age', '$Car')");

if (!$result) 
 die("SQL Error: ".mysql_error());

echo "Success";
```

Also

- Your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)
- Your script will always be executed, regardless whether the form was submitted or not - you want to change that to prevent getting empty records

Comment: Odd, though, he's got the mysql_error stuff at the end of the query - that should have spit out a syntax error at minimum, given the missing quotes.

Comment: @Marc nope, because the expression inside the brackets was `<some string> OR die`. The `<some string>` portion would always evaluate to `true`, satisfying the condition, so the interpreter would never even look at the die() statement. The query got executed, and crashed with an error. This is why `or die()` constructions are a bad thing

Comment: Ah yeah, missed the missing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that `Username`, `Password` and `Car` are strings so it should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdata` (Username,Password,Age,Car) VALUES ('$Username', '$Password', $Age, '$Car')") or die(mysql_error();
```

Good advice - try using PDO ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your variables with '' so the SQL will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your `VALUES` statement, you need to wrap the $Username in a single quote.

`VALUES ('$Username', '$Password', $Age, '$Car')"`

Also, I would remove the `or die` statement from your call.  Then, I would test the `$result` in a `if` statement.

`if ($result)`