# JS/PHP/MySQL Success but not Inserted

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a array containing objects and I want to store these objects into my MySQL DB. At the beginning it worked quite fine, but suddenly it stopped working even though it did not make any changes to the code or the DB.

The array of object looks as follows: `var geocoded = [{zip: 1234, place: "XY", country: "XY", lat: "123.123", lng: "123.123"}, ...];`

I use the following JS code to iterate over the array and post each object to the DB. kiter is the iterator I use and is defined as `geocoded.length - 1`

```
function postPlaces(data, kiter) {

  if (kiter >= 0) {
    $.post("api/placessave.php", 
      data[kiter],
      function(data, status){
        kiter--;
        postPlaces(geocoded, kiter);
        console.log(data + '.............' + status);
      }
    );
  } else {
        //statusUpdate(id);
  }
}
```

placessave.php looks as follows:

```
<?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USERNAME', 'root');
 define('PASSWORD','*****');
 define('DB','****');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

 $zip = $_POST['zip'];
 $place = $_POST['place'];
 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $lat = $_POST['lat'];
 $lng = $_POST['lng'];

 $sql = "insert ignore into places (zip, place, country, lat, lng) values ($zip, '$place', '$country', '$lat', '$lng')";

 if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
 echo "success";
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I use INSERT IGNORE because duplicates may exist but an update is not needed.
The interesting part is, that everything works quite nice I also get a Success on every query but nothing is stored to the DB.

Comment: what part of your code is failing - the sql or the ajax/javascript?

Comment: You're open to SQL injection attacks and, in many countries, zip/postcode is **not** numeric so `values ($zip, '$place',` will cause a problem (no quotes around `$zip`).

Comment: did you test it without `IGNORE` keyword?? just test it, if you are really getting success msg

Comment: have you tried echoing the sql an running it directly at db?

Comment: ^ +1 about the zipcode. Even here in the U.S. where it _appears_ to be a numeric value, there are places that start with 0, making it far better to treat it as a string.

Comment: or also check what r u getting in `print_r($_POST);` before query.

Comment: and have you tried to fetch a possible mysql-warning? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-warnings.php

Comment: and dont know why are u using `mysql_error()`? along with mysqli_*

Comment: and here is a long discussion about "insert Ignore" that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Anyone else find that *Thanks to Pekka for pointing this out.* comment a bit odd - almost like the code's been borrowed from another SO answer verbatim : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996106/php-and-mysql-not-inserting

Comment: Does not work without IGNORE either; I have only numeric zip codes, but this is a good hint thanks; I will now try to fetch possible mysql-warnings

Comment: @CD001 thats exactly where I got this piece from, tried to find some help here on stackoverflow... removed it again from my code ;-)

Comment: ;) you probably want to keep the `else { ... }` but instead of `die(mysql_error())` you'd want `die(mysqli_error())` - if the query fails then you'll get an error message explaining why; `IGNORE` will suppress that though so you don't want it there for the test... actually, you don't really want it at all ideally.

Comment: run manually in phpmyadmin `Insert ignore into places (zip, place, country, lat, lng) values (1234, 'XY', 'XY', '123.123', '123.123');`

Comment: Put echo before $sql and send the query it echoed here @eltomaco

Comment: And there may be another issue like the data is being ignored due to duplicate. Remove `IGNORE` and try it once

Comment: @SathvikCheela the problem was due to a `'` in a place name.

Comment: Okay, Have to able to figure it out, I mean your question have been solved or not

Answer (score 0):

Insert Query you have to change like this. You have Missed Quotes around the values

Replace

```
$sql = "insert ignore into places (zip, place, country, lat, lng) values ($zip, '$place', '$country', '$lat', '$lng')";
```

With

```
$sql = "insert ignore into places (zip, place, country, lat, lng) values ('".$zip."', '".$place."', '".$country."', '".$lat."', '".$lng."')";
```

Comment: Use `IGNORE` as suggested and check on to the post values are coming to this page after submission of the form. Ensure that you have placed all the elements inside the **<form>** attribute.

Comment: With the exception of the fact you've now put `'` marks around `$zip` this makes absolutely no difference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. The problem was in the data I wanted to store. I found that there was a place name which contained a `'`. Therefore the query did not work. After removing this, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

just change  `($zip,` in the query to `('$zip',`

`zip` is probably string and you are not passing it as string in the query. Moreover, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read about it to avoid insecurities.

Comment: `$zip` is a numeric, so no need of quotes